# How can i export whatsapp messages automatically?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, message, whatsapp

im cs student. We have a problem on department whatsapp group. When we chat, discuss about the non-departmental issues other ones says we are not able to be aware of important messages about lectures because there are a lot of messages. I thought maybe i can make an program which is analyze messages and saves which starts with ** symbols. Than i wanna make an web app so when we wanna check if there is important messages. The problem is about taking the messages from whatsapp. When you want to export the messages you should do it manually with clicking on mobile app. I thought i can make a bot with python selenium which goes to the web.whatsapp and do the things right there and export the messages. But i cant export messages on web because there is no button for that on web. Even if i can export the messages via that way, is that correct way to do that? What should i do.

Comment: Is this a class assignment where you're supposed to extract content from a dynamic webpage, or are you trying to fix a *social problem* (people using an important group for inane chat) with technology? A simpler fix is to just create another group specifically for an informal talk, kick people who insist on blabbering in the main group. Or use other app like Discord that's better suited for this, supporting multiple channel for a "server"

Comment: The first one. Actually you are right but i just want to exercise about python and problem solving. If the program does it automatically, that is better to just check the webpage than doing manually with more group or take everyone to the discord.

Comment: Yea the selenium way will be to scroll up until the last checked point (your app should keep this value somewhere), then parse every element.

Comment: thanks, when i try to get web.whatsapp with selenium that requires scanning qr code. Actually i can access on my firefox web.whatsapp without qr anymore. Whats the problem and how to solve?

Comment: The default Selenium behavior is to use a throwaway session. Lookup on how to run it with a permanent session, allow it to launch, manually scan the QR, then reuse the profile. Your can even copy this profile to a cloud VM for headless operation

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best automation practice in selenium

For multiple reasons, logging into sites like Gmail and Facebook using WebDriver is not recommended. Aside from being against the usage terms for these sites (where you risk having the account shut down), it is slow and unreliable.

The ideal practice is to use the APIs that email providers offer, or in the case of Facebook the developer tools service which exposes an API for creating test accounts, friends, and so forth. Although using an API might seem like a bit of extra hard work, you will be paid back in speed, reliability, and stability. The API is also unlikely to change, whereas webpages and HTML locators change often and require you to update your test framework.

Logging in to third-party sites using WebDriver at any point of your test increases the risk of your test failing because it makes your test longer. A general rule of thumb is that longer tests are more fragile and unreliable.

WebDriver implementations that are W3C conformant also annotate the navigator object with a WebDriver property so that Denial of Service attacks can be mitigated.

Comment: yeah firstly i thought about solving this via api's. But the point is, when i search on google i find about whatsapp business api, that says you should verify your business. I dont have business. There are also services like twilio. Are these services correct for this problem?